# how to update a map value (of type table<String>) in Realtime db (Flutter)?

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I'm trying to add a new value to the table choices (which is an element in a map<string,dynamic>). How can I do it ?[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to add an element to an array in the Firebase Realtime Database without first reading the entire array. So you'll have to:

1. Read the current elements in the array
2. Add the item to the array
3. Write the entire array back to the database

This is one of the (many) reasons why Firebase recommends against using arrays for list-like structures and prefers using lists or maps. I recommend checking out [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).